# Does the Visual Studio debugger for Python have equivalent to F9 key matlab

Tags: python, matlab, visual-studio, debugging

Is there an equivalent to the <kbd>F9</kbd> key in Matlab for Visual Studio when debugging Python? It allows one to evaluate any expression one comes across, as long as the values have already been calculated with of course.

I.e. if I'm debugging something in Matlab, and I come across the statement `x = a+b+c`, and I'm not sure what `a+b` is, I can highlight it, press <kbd>F9</kbd>, and get the answer.

This is really nice for complicated formulas and checking piece by piece whether it all works out, instead of splitting everything up and creating unnecessary variables to assign the results too

Comment: The Python debugger allows for arbitrary expressions to be executed. Just copy the expression, and paste it to run it. It works much like the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Python is a language. Keys are specific to an IDE. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: This is not really a feature of the Matlab language, but rather of the Editor/IDE. You need a Python editor that does the same thing. Also note that F9 is not used on all platforms, e.g., Shift+F7 is used by default on OS X.

Comment: I'm using VS2015. Martijn where would I paste it to? I can't modify my code while it's running with print statements can I.

Comment: @Nimitz14: you confused me by talking about the *Python debugger*, so I assumed you meant the [`pdb` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). Visual Studio is an entirely different product with its own debugger, not one that comes with Python itself.

Comment: @Nimitz14: I have no experience with the VS debugger. I've edited your question to reflect that you are using that debugger, and not the standard library textual debugger.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Should have realized that.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442196/does-python-debugger-have-equivalent-to-f9-key-matlab/32442265#comment52748366_32442196) and [horchler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442196/does-python-debugger-have-equivalent-to-f9-key-matlab/32442265#comment52748372_32442196) you need an IDE that supports this feature. One such IDE is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) which has a similar functionality using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> while debugging.

Comment: Damn, I'm using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I really should have just spent 5 minutes looking on my own. In VS it's called quick-watch, can be accessed with shift f9.